# How to pass a Range type value to a String Type variable

Tags: string, excel, vba, range

I am using code that I got from 101 Ready-to_use Macros by Michael Alexander and John Walkenbach.

In this code they specify the range values in the code. I want the users to be able to select the values. I'm getting errors after I've appeared to successfully have the user enter the value of the range. To help me debug the problem I've just written a short macro to test what i'm trying to do. But I can't seem to pass the information to the message box so I can see that it is working (although it appears to, be becuase when the user selects the range the address shows up in the entry box.) I cannot figure out how to take the user supplied RANGE type and turn it into a STRING value to show in my message or to use it as a Range. Now as a newbie, I'm now thinking this little test is more important than the original problem to help be learn to debug.

(I've tried some different variations including making the AS RANGE as AS Variant and trying to make a StringVariable assigned the value of the RANGE (e.g. UserRange = Rng1 Where UserRange is type String and Rng1 is type Range):

***Here is my code***

```
Sub SelectRange()
     Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("select cell", Type:=8)
MsgBox ("You selected " & Rng1 & "as the range")
End Sub
```

**Here was the original code:**

```
Sub Macro101()

' I've already changed Step#4 to read the worksheet name instead of C20
' I'm now trying to change Step#3 to let the user select the range but
' I'm having problems using the input from the user becuase I've made that 
' Variable as Range (Not shown here).


'Step 1:  Declare your variables
    Dim pp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim xlwksht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim MyRange As String
    Dim MyTitle As String
    Dim Slidecount As Long


'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
    Set pp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True


'Step 3:  Set the ranges for your data and title
    MyRange = "A1:J29"


'Step 4:  Start the loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    MyTitle = xlwksht.Range("C20").Value


'Step 5:  Copy the range as picture
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange).CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


'Step 6:  Count slides and add new slide as next available slide number
    Slidecount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(Slidecount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    PPSlide.Select


'Step 7:  Paste the picture and adjust its position
    PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 100


'Step 8:  Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet
    PPSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = MyTitle
    Next xlwksht


'Step 9:  Memory Cleanup
    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Range.Address property, like so:

```
Sub SelectRange()

    Dim Rng1 As Range

    On Error Resume Next    'If the user presses cancel, it would cause an error
    Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select Cell", "Range Selection", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove the On Error Resume Next condition
    If Rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    MsgBox ("You selected " & Rng1.Address & " as the range")

End Sub
```

I also like to make sure there won't be an error if the user presses cancel, and I like to use the current selection as the default.

Comment: Thank you Tigeravatar. You are absolutely correct about needing that error checking. I hit cancel a few times myself while just testing. I'll include this in the main module I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to conver the `Range` to a string, you need to use its address property, which is already a string

```
Sub SelectRange()
     Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("select cell", Type:=8)
MsgBox ("You selected " & Rng1.Address & "as the range")
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! That solved that problem. It's always amazing how hard it is when you don;t know how and how easy the solution is with someone that knows what they are doing. Thank you very much. Now I can continue on with my studying.